# How does 'Top SQL - By Application' values from SQL sentry correlates

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning

I have run a performance simulation on my application server and pull the sentry report for my analysis. And While going through the top sql -by application, I found difficult to correlates the values in the report. Any thoughts on this?
Means, Count, Total Duration, Total CPU, Total Reads & Total Writes values signify?

please refer the screenshot attached for report
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you run `SELECT session_id, program_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions`, you'll see in the program_name column whatever name the application developer decided to put there.  So in the case of SQL Server Management Studio, you'll see "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" in that column.  What you see there is completely dependent on what the application developer specified, so it may be blank if they decided not to put anything there.

The program_name column is what most of the monitoring tools are using for aggregation by "application."